REGEXP_REPLACE not working as expected in Databricks to add spaces to string
I have a line of code to add spaces to a string after every 3 characters for a given column below:
regexp_replace(column, '(.{3})', '$1 ') as new_column

When running this code manually in SQL editor of Databricks, it inserts the data into the table as expected. However, when executing the same code as part of a Databricks job/workflow to populate the column in the insert table, the column in the insert table has null values.
The cluster used for job compute uses Spark 3.4.1.
Here's an example:
insert overwrite table
select
regexp_replace(column, '(.{3})', '$1 ') as new_column
from table

Input Data:
| column     |
| ---------- |
| 0QW1ER2RT  |

Expected Output:
| new_column  |
| ----------- |
| 0QW 1ER 2RT |

Any idea why regexp_replace does not working properly (i.e. inserting null in column) when ran part of a workflow in a Databricks job to populate a column but work when executed manually in Databricks SQL editor? Any help or insights are greatly appreciated!

Spark uses Java regex, so it should work, the issue must be with the strings, or the data.

hmmm this workflow is of notebook type using sql language. Without the regexp expression, the data is populating just fine.

I observer same type of issue during Postgress & Yellobrick DB Regex Implementation.
Few Database not support () $& or $1 as matched substring.
Those type of database support Back references (\) as matched substring to capturing groups, range from 1 to 9 (\1 to \9).
So, please try this query in databricks-sql:
select regexp_replace(column, '(.{3})', '\1 ') as new_column;

-- or
-- use index from beginning (pos: 1)
select regexp_replace(column, '(.{3})', '\1 ', 1) as new_column;

MySQL Result: db<>fiddle (support '$1')
PL/pgSQL Result: db<>fiddle (support '\1')
YelloBrick Result: (support '\1') 
I hope your issue will be resolve.
Thank You !!!

That does not seem to be working for DBX sql. It just replaced everything with 1 1 1 1 1 …

Try once with \\1,  carriage return. Is there any online DBX sql oneline Compiler ? @TyahDugger
